# C++ - Microsoft Visual Studio - Could not find part of the path "..."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to create a C++ Windows Universal App on Windows 10.
When I try an start a new project I get the following error message:

[image]

When I click OK I get this message:

[image]

---

If anyone could help my out I would be very grateful.

Comment: have you verified that the path exists?

Comment: What's your visual studio version. What project you are creating?